# How to revert formated partition?

Tags: windows-7, formatting

While installing Windows 7, I accidently formatted a partition (D drive) while I was trying to install Windows on the system partition (C drive).

I know that it is possible to revert this situation, but I do not know how. Please help me out with instructions or which tools to use. The partition has `just` been formatted and nothing has been written to it yet.

Answer (score 0):

There are several utilities that will do this.  Here is one of the best:

http://www.easeus.com/resource/windows-7-Unformat.htm

http://www.easeus.com/datarecoverywizard/free-data-recovery-software.htm

There is a free version, but you may need to use the paid version if your partition was a dynamic partition.

Answer (score 0):

There are many [variations of this question](https://superuser.com/search?q=recover+formatted) - It seems to me that [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) appears in many of the answers

Comment: Thanks, with Recuva I get almost all important data back.

Comment: @Janez: I'm glad you succeeded. If you think my answer was useful please consider upvoting it and/or accepting it (click the tick symbol)