# How to recover my data lost when installing new OS?

Tags: windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to revert formated partition?](https://superuser.com/questions/340901/how-to-revert-formated-partition)

My desktop has partition Local disk C and D. The OS Windows XP SP2 installed on local disk C.
When I was Installed new fresh copy of Windows XP instead of Installed in Local disk C!, Am install in Local disk D.
How to recover my Back up data lost?.

Comment: Restore from backup.

Answer (score 0):

You can recover some files if you made a fast format of your partition while installing windows. Fast formating will only delete the table which stores informations about where the file is physically on the disk.
Some recovery tools will scan you drive, and if it find some files it will recover them.
But you won't recover everything. You have certainly crashed some data at the exact location where the new windows installed.

You can try to find some data recovery tool. Here is one which provides one gig of data recovery for free : http://www.easeus.com/datarecoverywizard/free-data-recovery-software.htm

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways in how you can recover your data/partitions. A lot of desktop applications in Windows exist but if you want to recover it independently of your OS, then you can use open source tools such as TestDisk wich are also bootable as a Live CD. You can find more information here:

http://blog.eddsn.com/2011/02/how-to-recover-lost-or-deleted-partitions/